# How can I remotely send an SMS message through my Mac from my iPhone?

Tags: macos, iphone, software-recommendation, applications

Is there an application for Mac OS X which would allow me to remotely send SMS messages through my iPhone? Ideally, just a simple application or maybe a full screen remote application like [TeamViewer](http://www.teamviewer.com/).

I prefer a free solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [**myPhoneDesktop**](http://www.myphonedesktop.com/).

This solution has an iPhone and Mac (or Windows) client and sends a push notification from the Mac app to the iPhone with the information for a call, text, URL, text or an image. The iPhone app then opens the data sent to it by the Mac app.

The iPhone app [costs $4.99 in the App Store](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/jproductivity-llc/id352226779?mt=8) and the Mac app is free. myPhoneDesktop requires an account to be set up, but it is free.

Comment: Does this App Actually send a sms THROUGH the phone. Or as I interpret it, Only TO the phone.
If the latter then I do not think it is what the OP is looking for.
The Addressbook.app on the Mac used to be able to connect to your phone via BT and send a SMS through the phone.
But that was discontinued by apple.
The  way it worked was the phone was just the conduit.
The sms went from the Mac passed through the phone to go out to the network carrier.  There was no addition manual interaction with the phone.

Comment: @markhunte - It will create a draft SMS on your iPhone with text and recipient entered in the desktop app. You will have to tap Send in order to send it. BTW, thanks for the improvements Matt!

Comment: The iPhone app [used to be $1.99 in 2010](http://appshopper.com/productivity/myphonedesktop-%E2%80%93-phone-on-your-desktop).

Answer (score 3):

Apple has actually just released this app which should do just that. It works only with ios5 and mac os10.7.3. Its called messages. It is a beta version of an app that will be on mountain lion.

I downloaded it from http://www.apple.com/macosx/mountain-lion/messages-beta/

Comment: cool! application from apple itself.

Comment: Will "messages" send messages to any SMS number? or only iChat subscribers?

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your use case, you could send SMS messages using Google Voice for free. Google allows you to port your mobile telephone number for a fee if keeping the same number is important. You would then be able to send SMS messages directly from your desktop, or anywhere else you have an internet connection and web browser.

If applicable, could you explain why you'd like to send the SMS through your iPhone instead of directly to the recipient?

Answer (score -1):

Maybe your mobile phone service provider has a web interface you can use to send text messages? I was also looking for a way to send SMS messages via iPhone on my Mac, and then found out that my service provider has this function they call "Web SMS": you just log in on their website, and can send messages from your phone number. If your service provider has something like this, it's a lot simpler than installing special apps on both Mac and iPhone.